# Oracle RAC database creates load on one server and client fails to connect

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Almost all the client connections are directed to one server and the application fails to connect after some time with IOException. Seems load balancing is not working properly. We are forced to restart the listener at this point.

jdbc URL : `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-ip)(PORT=1538))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=production)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))`

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Connection reset)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 64 more
```

Version:

```
11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit
```

Comment: Is there sever side load-balancing for the `production` service?

Comment: You can use [Load Balancing Advisor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/rac.111/b28252/configwlm.htm#TDPRC067)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure - when you say "all connection are directed to one node" - do you mean that the session are created on one node or that the scan listener taking care of the connection is only being used on one node?

Check and see if you SCAN address contain 3 IP addresses (*nslookup scan-ip*), make sure that your SCAN listeners are being distributed across nodes (*srvctl status scan* and *srvctl status scan_listener*). You can also check to see that the database service you're trying to use (production) is being registered on all appropriate listeners (check database parameter "remote_listener" to make sure where the service is being registered to).

Comment: 1. Sessions are created on one node      2.Checked suggestions, all are configured properly.

Comment: define "configured correctly"? do you have multiple scan listeners? are they listening on the correct port (1538)?

If I had to guess, instead of connecting to the scan listener, it seems that you're connecting to a local listener on one of the nodes (so there is no session redirect by the scan listener)